# Updating Sharepoint using Flow and Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow

I have a SharePoint list and want to update a specific field using Excel and Flow.

I understand how to pull the Excel table (using Get List Rows Present) and then to pull up the Update Item action however I'm unsure how to tell Flow which field in the Excel table relates to the Id in SharePoint (i.e. the one described as 'Unique Identifier of Item to be Updated')

Sorry - I'm a novice, so simple responses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel table is formatted as a Table, then Flow should be able to read and provide those column headers as dynamic field options to your SP list.  Unable to answer with any details without seeing your specific Flow parameters.  I would ask from a different perspective: is there a reason not to manage the information directly in the SP list, for a cleaner more efficient update?  Is there a reason that someone or some process has to update Excel and then a process has to query Excel to update SharePoint?